# dplyr function mutate_at throws Error: expecting a one sided formula, a function, or a function name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created the following dummy data frame, called **aa** :

```
a b
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

and the following code:

```
aa_ <- 
  aa %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars("a"),
            .funs = list(.*b))
```

throws the following error:

> Error: expecting a one sided formula, a function, or a function name.

What am I doing wrong?

PD: If I change **"a"** for **a** in the mutate_at command nothing changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `.` in `mutate_at` you need to specify `~`. Try :

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>%  mutate_at(.vars = vars("a"),.funs = list(~. * b))
```

However, `mutate_at` is used when you have a function to apply for more than one column. For only one column, you can directly do :

```
aa %>% mutate(a  = a * b)
```

Comment: True, I forgot I was creating an anonimous function. I am using mutate_at even thought I have only one column for the sake of simplicity, in my readl data frame I've got many. 
That solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_` without the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>%
   mutate_at(vars('a'), ~ . * b)
```